# Excel 1004 Run time error

Tags: excel

I know that this question has been answered many times before but I just can't figure out what is wrong.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim FileNum As Integer ' file num
    Dim DataLine As String ' line of file

    Dim entry() As String ' split line

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    Dim X_ As Integer ' cell x
    X_ = 0
    Dim Y_ As Integer ' cell y
    Y_ = 0


    Dim s As Variant

    FileNum = FreeFile() ' create a free file
    Open "C:\Users\vittorio\PycharmProjects\Fiddleheads\data.csv" For Input As #FileNum ' open the file
    While Not EOF(FileNum)
        Line Input #FileNum, DataLine ' read in data 1 line at a time
        'MsgBox (DataLine)
        entry = Split(DataLine, ",")

        For Each s In entry
            ActiveSheet.Cells(X_, Y_).Select
            X_ = X_ + 1
        Next s
        X_ = 0
        Y_ = Y_ + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

When using `ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select` I have no problems. But when I replace a variable for `Cells(1, 1)` I get an error. Anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting at `Cells(0, 0)` and this doesn't exist. Start Y_ and X_ at 1. You also need to reset X_ to 1 within the loop, not 0.

Comment: Funny, there actually is a dup answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14650140/2258

Comment: Another reason why life's funny.
Why can't excel by 0 based.

Comment: Could use `Offset()` instead.. but, yes, Excel is an oddball in this respect.